# User not changing SElinux context (SELinux User)

Tags: rhel, selinux

I've added multiple users to SELinux user contexts:

```
# semanage login -l 

Login Name           SELinux User         MLS/MCS Range        Service

__default__          unconfined_u         s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
bob                  staff_u              s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
phil                 staff_u              s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
root                 unconfined_u         s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
system_u             system_u             s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
tobias               sysadm_u             s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
useruuser            user_u               s0                   *
```

For all users except `useruuser` I have ran `restorecon -F -R -v /home/${USER}`, and I can verify that e.g user `phil` home directory has been updated:

```
$ ls -ldZ /home/phil/
drwx------. phil phil staff_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 /home/phil/
```

However if I try to switch to user phil and run `id -Z` I get unconfined.

```
$ id -Z
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

I've tried to create `/.autorelabel` and rebooted system without success.

The user `useruuser` was added following RHEL guide: [selinux_users_and_administrators_guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/index)

I've even tried to run `usermod -Z staff_u phil` without success.

**EDIT:** When I logged out from my SSH session and logged in using user phil, I got the desired result:

```
$ id -Z
staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

However this is not the case when running `su - phil` or any other form of `su`... Not sure if the reboot is the reason for this fix(?)